# Error: Main method not found in class ca.ab.bc.framework.FormData

Tags: java, web-applications

I set the CLASSPATH - C:\Workspace\src\current\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes

when I write the command (C:\Workspace\src\current\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes>java ca/ab/bc/framework/FormData) in cmd in order to run the class file "FormData", I'm getting this error message below. This FormData contain the package. Can anyone help me out by letting me know where is the problem? I have given a part of my code below for your review.

Error: Main method not found in class ca.ab.cimarron.framework.FormData, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

My code in "FormData":

```
package ca.ab.bc.framework;

import java.util.*;

 /*
  * Container for form data (form fields and upload files)
  *
  */

public class FormData {

  private String[][] requestHeader = null;

  private String[][] requestData = null;

  private List requestFiles = null;

  private boolean allowSideEffects = true;

  public FormData(String[][] header, String[][] data, List files) {

    requestHeader = header;
    requestData = data;
    requestFiles = files;

  }


  public boolean sideEffects() {

    return allowSideEffects;

  }


  public void noSideEffects() {

    allowSideEffects = false;

  }

  public String[][] getHeader() {

    return requestHeader;

  }
```

Comment: to start a java program, the class needs a main method declared like `public static void main(String[] args)` - which is the method that will be started/executed. Maybe check the tutorial: [The "Hello World!" Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) (and others on that trail)

Comment: but this code seems more like being for a web application or that like, if so that tutorial won't help (neither using the `java`command)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a main method in your class. You can only run classes which have a main method in them. A main method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //enter code you want to execute here
}
```

Also before you run a java program from a terminal, you need to compile it first. Say your main class is called FormData, then you need to do the following:

**javac FormData.java**
then
**java FormData**

Let me know if you have further questions :)

Comment: Hi @manzk ! thanks for the answer. Yes I did compile before running the program. I don't get any error while compiling but only get that error when I want to run the class file created just after the compilation. I think its something in the code I need to check. Also adding public static void m....giving me error in compilation though